# postgresql jdbc: FATAL: database does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a database using the following code:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Model {

        Connection connection;

        Model() {

                try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:localhost:5432/deliverp", "kais", "0000");
                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        static {

                try {
                        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public boolean addClient(Object data[]) {

                return true;
        }
}
```

But after running the Java program I receive the following stack trace:

```
Nov 17, 2017 8:58:24 AM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "localhost:5432/deliverp" does not exist
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2603)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:125)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:227)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at Model.<init>(Model.java:16)
        at DelivERP.<init>(DelivERP.java:42)
        at DelivERP.main(DelivERP.java:104)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "localhost:5432/deliverp" does not exist
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2603)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:125)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:227)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at Model.<init>(Model.java:16)
        at DelivERP.<init>(DelivERP.java:42)
        at DelivERP.main(DelivERP.java:104)
```

Therefore I wanted to make sure that the database exists by running the test below:

```
kais@debian:~/Documents/DelivERP$ psql deliverp
psql (9.6.4)
Type "help" for help.

deliverp=> \d
             List of relations
 Schema |      Name      | Type  |  Owner   
--------+----------------+-------+----------
 public | BusinessEntity | table | postgres
 public | Client         | table | postgres
 public | Company        | table | postgres
 public | Order          | table | postgres
 public | Product        | table | postgres
(5 rows)

deliverp=>
```

It sounds to me weird that the server didn't find the database although it exists ..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your URL is wrong, it should be `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/deliverp` (note the `//` before localhost).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yup, right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/deliverp", "kais", "0000");
```

or

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:deliverp", "kais", "0000");
```

Comment: And it was a URL issue .. Thanks for pointing that out - problem solved :)